# Entry is saved but the data is not saved in Strapi 4 Content-type

Tags: strapi

I am learning Strapi in version 4.  Through strapi admin,
I have created a content type named "Events" and created some
entries. These entries, which I created in strapi admin, are
perfectly saved and committed to the backend sqlite database.

But, when I make a post request through my programme, the
entry is saved but data is not saved. Or even when I make a post
request through postman, the entry is saved but the data is not saved
in the new entry.

My javascript programme reads as under:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const URL ='http://localhost:1337/api/events'

const obj = {
    data : {
        attributes: {
            name: 'test',
            venue : 'town hall',
            address : 'test',
            date : '2022-11-20',
            time : '10 pm',
            performers : 'test',
            description : 'test from js programme',
            user : 'test'
        }
    }
}

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: URL,
    data: obj
}).then((res)=>console.log(res.data)).
catch ((err)=> console.log(err.message))

/*  response received is as under with 
    status code 200 on strapi server side

{
data: {
    id: 57,
    attributes: {
    name: null,
    slug: null,
    venue: null,
    address: null,
    date: null,
    time: null,
    performers: null,
    description: null,
    createdAt: '2022-11-10T13:24:26.335Z',
    updatedAt: '2022-11-10T13:24:26.335Z',
    publishedAt: '2022-11-10T13:24:26.332Z'
    }
},
meta: {}
}

*/
```

Screen shot of my postman request is as under:

[image]

**Surprisingly, the strapi backend console displays response
code 200.  The entry is saved, but the data is not saved in
content type.**

All CRUD permissions for content type "Events" are public.
I am not in a position to figure out what I am doing wrong
here.

Community, please help me, in my learning.

Answer (score 0):

You should be probably make

```
const obj = {
    data : {
        attributes: {
            name: 'test',
            venue : 'town hall',
            address : 'test',
            date : '2022-11-20',
            time : '10 pm',
            performers : 'test',
            description : 'test from js programme',
            user : 'test'
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
const obj = {
    data : {
            name: 'test',
            venue : 'town hall',
            address : 'test',
            date : '2022-11-20',
            time : '10 pm',
            performers : 'test',
            description : 'test from js programme',
            user : 'test'
        }
}
```

Please have a look at documentation here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#create-an-entry

In post requests you do not need to put data in `attributes` key.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  This too gives the same result.  Although all CRUD permissions for the content type are public, is there anything else which is required in this case?  Kindly throw light on this aspect.